# Преобразование строки "false" в логическое false

Tags: javascript

Есть ли в JS метод наподобие `parseFloat`, который бы мог преобразовать строку `"false"` в `Boolean false`?

История вопроса: в БД MongoDB поле имеет логическое значение: `visible: true || false`. В админке сайта этому полю соответствует `select` со значениями `true` и `false`. Но эти значения являются строками. Надо перевести их в `boolean` тип. С помощью `if` это сделать легко, но может быть есть метод специальный?

Comment: Нет, такой функции нету. Пишите сравнение со строкой.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, спасибо за ответ!)

Comment: можно взять решение из англ.версии вопроса: true только если выполняется равенство - `value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").toLowerCase() === "true"`
(С) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219105/javascript-parsing-a-string-boolean-value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь JSON.parse, правда это достаточно специфичный метод, необходимо чтобы приходило точно "true" или "false" (именно в нижнем регистре). Неверная переданная строка вызовет ошибку.

```
JSON.parse("true") // true
JSON.parse("false") // false
```

Comment: Благодарю!) Интересно узнать как это работает)

Comment: @Дмытрык в спецификации (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) написано что "Возвращает объект Object, соответствующий переданной строке JSON text." А boolean это как раз объект:)

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин нет, `boolean` - это как раз не объект, а один из 5 примитивных типов.

Comment: @Regent согласен, неправильно, хотел написать про объект Boolean который является объектом оберткой...

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин а при чем тут `Boolean`? `JSON.parse("true")` ведь возвращает именно примитив.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал просто:

```
s === "true"
```

Comment: Я не понимаю. Можете привести пример?

Comment: @Regent, да, накосячил. `s !== "false"` или `s === "true"`.

Comment: @Дмытрык, исправил.

Comment: Понятно) Но мне первый вариант больше нравится, т.к. там можно использовать переменную, а в Вашем варианте нужно использовать два разных оператора (это уже применительно к конкретной ситуации)

Comment: @Дмытрык, какие ещё 2 оператора? Всё то же самое.

Comment: @Дмытрык о чём вы? `var result = dbValue === "true";` и вперёд.

Comment: @Regent, точно. Спасибо, что "открыли глаза"! Я, как бы, понял, направление мысли Qwertiy, но у моего знания JS еще нет гибкости)