# Перевод из String в Boolean

Tags: javascript

Как я могу перевести из `STRING` в `Boolean`:

```js
let a='false';
console.log(Boolean(a));//выводит true, а мне нужно false
```

Comment: `console.log(a==='true');`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/816298/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-false-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-false

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = 'false';
console.log(JSON.parse(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    a = JSON.parse("false".toLowerCase());
    console.log(typeof(a))
```

Так будет правильнее